# SparkR dapply fails with arrays as input

Tags: r, arrays, apache-spark, sparkr

I am working with the `dapply` (and also `dapplyCollect`) functions in SparkR which fail when arrays are used as the input.

My input data are in a SparkDataFrame read from a parquet file from a pre-existing process (I cannot change anything relating to this process). This dataframe consists of many million rows and several columns of data stored as arrays. Here is a simplified example created from an R dataframe.

```
> R.df <- data.frame(key = 1:3)
> R.df$data <- list(seq(1, 10))
> R.df
  key                          data
1   1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
2   2 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
3   3 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

The same dataframe converted to a SparkDataFrame:

```
> Spark.df <- createDataFrame(R.df)
> Spark.df
SparkDataFrame[key:int, data:array<int>]
```

Next, we do the processing with a custom function and an error is thrown:

```
my.complicated.process <- function(partition) {
  ## Here we would do something to each partition
  ## For this test, return data unchanged
  return(partition)
}

spark.results <- dapply(Spark.df, my.complicated.process, schema(Spark.df))
head(spark.results)

Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 55.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 55.0 (TID 55, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),  : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
Calls: compute -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$5.apply(objects.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$5.apply(objects.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInter
```

I have managed workarounds to solve this:

1. Following the example [here](https://gist.github.com/clarkfitzg/08ad74e2099f51e5138b3e0ba72bdc07). By using `serialize` and `unserialize` to convert the array to simple binary type. This has the disadvantage of having to serialise before the SparkDataFrame is created.
2. By converting the array to a comma-separated string e.g. by using `to_json`, then using a combination of `strsplit`, `paste` and `as.integer` in R and `split`, `cast` in SparkR to go between a numeric array and a string
3. By using `explode` in SparkR to split the array column into multiple rows and pivoting the dataframe to get columns, then using `dapply` over these new columns.

None of these solutions are optimal, so I was hoping to find a way for `dapply` to both take array types as inputs and also return array types.

I am using R v3.6.3 with SparkR v2.4.5.